# Why did we move to this quiet little mountain town?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Right off the get-go in *The Stick of Truth*, the new kid's parents **strongly** imply that there is a reason that we moved.

> **Dad**: Son, do you remember why we moved to this quiet little mountain town?
>   **Kid**: *Blank stare*
>   **Dad**: He doesn't remember--
>   **Mom**: He doesn't remember at all
>   **Dad**: That's good, that's good he doesn't remember.

What's behind that exchange?

Comment: Short of giving an answer, you could try playing through the game to see if it is answered.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it ended up being a major part of the story that will naturally be revealed as you play through the game. While I haven't played far enough to find out myself either, this feels sort of like playing the first 20 minutes of BioShock and then asking "why is Rapture in ruins?"

Comment: And to those who ask why others find lore questions distasteful... "This is clearly foreshadowing, BUT I AM IMPATIENT" is a prime example of why.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the game... *(spoilers ahead)*

> It's revealed that your real name is Dovahkiin, the Dragonborn *(obvious reference to Skyrim)*.  You have an inhuman ability to make friends on any social network - before you were 5 years old, you had 3.2 billion friends on Facebook alone.  The game's X-Files-like government organization attempted to capture you to use your ability for themselves, but failed, and your family went into hiding.
>
>  Though exactly what happened when the government tried to capture you is never explained, it was apparently traumatizing enough that you blocked it from your memory.
>
>  [Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=340eOIyrXBQ#t=19m50s)

Comment: Maybe one of the government spooks farted on his balls.